# EF6 takes time to fetch results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, entity

We're using EF6 with repository pattern to handle the DB data and using LINQ to get the data back. The query generated by EF fetches around 164thousand records in 100-120 seconds in SSMS and maps the results back to C# objects. If I log the time taken to execute, it seems to be taking time for materializing the results to C# objects. Below are the log details for query execution in EF-

Opened connection asynchronously at 6/20/2016 2:47:04 PM +05:30
-- Executing asynchronously at 6/20/2016 2:47:04 PM +05:30
-- Completed in 8730 ms with result: SqlDataReader
My questions is- why is EF taking time to map results back to C# objects.

More details-

```
_fundRepository.GetAllIncluding(f => f.Funds.Select(l => l.Location),
                    f => f.Brand).Select(f => new
//properties selection from above entities
.
.
.
);
```

Fund entity has many objects in it.. Fund and its child products count to be around 164000 as mentioned above

Comment: Why would you need to materialize 164 000 records? Displaying of such number of records to the end user doesn't make sense... Maybe what you need is some kind of pagination?

Comment: Are you building up the whol object tree? Running a constructor can take up to 20-40 ms, especially if it has a lots of child objects.
EF is not for speed, it is for easy use. Optimize your code to get better performance.

Comment: No, I am not displaying it on UI. I'm giving this result as Export to the user.Thanks for response.

Comment: @Dexion - I tried replace code with SP and it looks like there is bit of improvement in it. however, I would like to know how the process of binding the query result to C# objects/entities happens when called from entity framework. I tried searching on google, however I did not get it.

Comment: Debug the code and stop the debugger on en EF call. You will see some runtime generated classes with generated names. 
Btw, here is the source code: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Answer (score 0):

U can use task to increse the performance of query like

```
Task.Run(()=>_fundRepository.GetAllIncluding(f => f.Funds.Select(l => l.Location),
                    f => f.Brand).Select(f => new
//properties selection from above entities
.
.
.
));
```

[Improve query performance](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38174/How-to-improve-your-LINQ-query-performance-by-X)

Comment: How that should improve the performance? The fact that you are executing request in another thread doesn't affect performance imo.

Comment: Yes What i meant processing time will be less

Comment: Why should it be less? The time for execution of the request should be exactly the same, the only good thing - you are not blocking UI Thread while waiting, so GUI is not frozen. But it doesn't answer OP question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a read only operation, putting AsNoTracking in the request may speed up performance, especially with this high number of records retrieved.

It would most likely need to go into your GetAllIncluding method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556203.aspx

and Section 5.1.1 here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#5

Comment: Thanks Eric. I tried that earlier, however I did not get any improvement.